# Javascript Function in a HTML not called

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with a javascript below written in the head part,

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
    var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
    var err = 0;
    if (isNaN(apple)) {
        err += 1;
    }
    if (err != 0) {
        alert('Please check your input!');
        return false;
    } else return true; }}
 </script>
```

Then the form is shown below:

```
   <form name="orderForm" onSubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">  
        <div class="input-control text span5">
              <input class="span5" type="text" placeholder="Each @ $4.9" id="apple" name="apple" onChange='checkApple(this.value)'>
    </div>
   </form>
```

When I submit the form, no alert message even the input is not number, may I know what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: You have a `}` missing.

Comment: Didn't check it myself, but test the function for errors. Like this `<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return myCheckFn()">` This will prevent the page from unloading, so that you'll be able to see errors.

Comment: After lining up your code, it appears you have a syntax error - missing a closing bracket on your function.  Check the JavaScript console on your browser and post what errors you see (if any).

Comment: Also `err != 0` is always true!

Comment: bracket was all correct in the actual code, edited the code above and it does not work

Answer (score 7):

You have not closed the first opening bracket. May I suggest you improve your formatting (tabs) to make it easier to see these mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing bracket } at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
function validateForm()
{
    var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
    var err   = 1;
    if(isNaN(apple)){
        err += 1;
    }
    if(err !=0){
        alert('Please check your input!');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

you are missing the last 2 `}`

Comment: the bracket was all completed in the actual code, the function was ont triggered, when i submit, even with wrong input, the form is still submitted

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function validateForm()
    {
      var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
      var err   = 1;
      if(isNaN(apple)){
          err += 1;
      }
      if(err !=0)
          {
            alert('Please check your input!');
            return false;
        }
        else
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

for to complete "}" in end :(

Comment: the bracket was all completed in the actual code, the function was ont triggered, when i submit, even with wrong input, the form is still submitted

Answer (score 1):

You have to close js functions brackets:

```
<script>
        function validateForm() {
            var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
            var err = 1;
            if (isNaN(apple)) {
                err += 1;
            }
            if (err != 0) {
                alert('Please check your input!');
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and format code proper : Also you forgot close `}` for main `function`.

```
function validateForm() 
{
    var apple = document.getElementById('apple').value;
    var err   = 1;
    if(isNaN(apple)) {
       err += 1;
    }
    if(err != 0) {
       alert('Please check your input!');
       return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    } 
}
```